# Form corners cut at an angle

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

How can I make the corners in the form cut at an angle?
Maybe something do with Viewbox?
[image: form corners]

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. What is this thing? Is it a Shape on a Canvas? A Window? A Control? The world's strangest looking ComboBox? Give us some clues please!

Comment: What a combo box? The word "form" is not exactly a ComboBox. I want to understand how to create windows of irregular shape, not only with rounded corners. As an example in the above picture.

Comment: I would recommend looking into the [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object and the [Geomentry mini-lanauge](https://rcosic.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/wpf-geometry-mini-language/) that the `Path.Data` property can use. What you'll end up wanting is a transparent Window or UserControl, with the border drawn using a custom `<Path>` object that draws the shape you're looking for.

Comment: That's the Form.'Region property at work.  Available in Winforms, not in WPF.  If you don't want to fake it with a borderless window then googling "wpf setwindowrgn" can provide you with hits.

Comment: Do you care if you can resize the window?

Comment: To begin, I would like to just deal with the problem. Then, yes of course, I care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wee bit clunky and has some caveats, but it does pretty much what you're asking for. It's just a transparent Window containing a Border. The Border has a Clip mask applied to it that knocks 20 x 20 x 20 pixel sided triangles off the corners. If you wanted to include the 'trenches' at the sides of the above image all you need to do is add a few more LineSegments to the Border's PathFigure.

You can't currently resize the Window. If you did implement resizing, you'd need to hook into the SizeChanged event of the Border to dynamically change the co-ordinates of the Border's clipping path in codebehind.

The Window has no maximise/minimise/close controls. You'd need to implement these yourself. Shouldn't be too big a job.

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmLight4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Width="1024"
        Height="768"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Background="Transparent"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        WindowStyle="None"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        x:Name="myWindow">

    <Border Background="Black">
        <Border.Clip>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                    <LineSegment Point="20,0" />
                    <LineSegment Point="1004,0" />
                    <LineSegment Point="1024,20" />
                    <LineSegment Point="1024,748" />
                    <LineSegment Point="1004,768" />
                    <LineSegment Point="20,768" />
                    <LineSegment Point="0,748" />
                    <LineSegment Point="0,20" />
                    <LineSegment Point="20,0" />
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Border.Clip>

        <!-- All of your everything else needs to go inside the border -->

    </Border>

</Window>
```